# Entity saving to database wrong date format codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, date, format, entity, codeigniter-4

My entity looks like this:

```
class Request extends Entity
{
    protected $casts = [
        'id'                => 'integer',
        'added_at'          => 'datetime',
        'deadline'          => 'datetime',
        'completed'         => 'integer'
    ]; 
}
```

When saving, the model generates the date fields in 'Y/m/d' format for the sql query, hovewer my database can not parse this. How can I force it to generate dates in 'Y-m-d' format when calling `$myModel->insert($myEntity)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entities has the option of setters. It performs the validation or conversion in your case whenever you perform save an entity. Lets say you want to change the form of `deadline` in that case you have to set the Setter for your `deadline` as follow :

```
public function setDeadline(string $dateString)
{
    $this->attributes['deadline'] = $dateString;

    return $this;
}
```

In the following line : `$this->attributes['deadline'] = $dateString;` You will use some library like Carbon to format the `$dateString` and then reassign your variable deadline. Reference link :
https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/models/entities.html